# How to read Scala code with lots of implicits?

Tags: scala, reading-code

Consider the following code fragment (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12265946/1333025):

```scala
// Using scalaz 6
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

object Example extends App {
  case class Container(i: Int)

  def compute(s: String): State[Container, Int] = state {
    case Container(i) => (Container(i + 1), s.toInt + i)
  }

  val d = List("1", "2", "3")

  type ContainerState[X] = State[Container, X]

  println( d.traverse[ContainerState, Int](compute) ! Container(0) )
}
```

I understand what it does on high level. But I wanted to trace what exactly happens during  the call to `d.traverse` at the end. Clearly, `List` doesn't have `traverse`, so it must be `implicit`ly converted to another type that does. Even though I spent a considerable amount of time trying to find out, I wasn't very successful. First I found that there is a method in `scalaz.Traversable`

```scala
traverse[F[_], A, B] (f: (A) => F[B], t: T[A])(implicit arg0: Applicative[F]): F[T[B]]
```

but clearly this is not it (although it's most likely that "my" `traverse` is implemented using this one). After a lot of searching, I grepped scalaz source codes and I found `scalaz.MA`'s method

```scala
traverse[F[_], B] (f: (A) => F[B])(implicit a: Applicative[F], t: Traverse[M]): F[M[B]]
```

which seems to be very close. Still I'm missing to what `List` is converted in my example and if it uses `MA.traverse` or something else.

---

**The question is: What procedure should I follow to find out what exactly is called at `d.traverse`?**

Having even such a simple code that is so hard analyze seems to me like a big problem. Am I missing something very simple?

How should I proceed when I want to understand such code that uses a lot of imported `implicit`s? Is there some way to ask the compiler what `implicit`s it used? Or is there something like [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for Scala so that I can search for a method just by its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: use the`-Xprint:typer` when compiling. I also asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498750/find-used-implicits-in-the-scala-repl/).

As for Hoogle, we have [Scalex](http://scalex.org/). You can even use it from sbt via a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use implicit hints in IntelliJ.

[image]